# huge kern.log and syslog files:

Tags: 22.04, disk-usage, disk, syslog, ubuntu-drivers

Ubuntu 22.04, when I analyzed the disk space, just realized that my kern.log and syslog files are getting huge, taking gigabytes of my disk space. When I opened the files, I saw a similar pattern in both, having the following type of messages repeated many many times:

```
Mar  3 19:19:57 mycomp kernel: [   12.902761] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 01000000 [] ch 0 [007f8ff000 DRM] subc 0 mthd 0008 data 00000000
```

I am really new to Linux, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: it seems you need nvidia module. `ubuntu-drivers devices` please add this through [edit] to your question.

Comment: Read, and reread, `man journalctl`. Simply `rm`ing the file while some process has it open will lead to huge, sparse files.

Comment: Typically, the underlying syslog behavior is to accumulate repeat messages and then write "_last message repeated X times_". However, if those messages are slightly different then that will not occur. Are the messages slightly different? Or do you see the log message "_last message repeated X times_"?